# Searching for multiple values across multiple columns without repetitive code?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Consider the simple WHERE Clause:

```
WHERE HomeZipCode = 12345
```

Simple, right?  But what if you want to look for multiple ZIP codes?

```
WHERE HomeZipCode IN (12345, 34567, 56789)
```

I love the IN operator.

Today I learned that you can conceptually reverse the IN statement to search for a specific value in multiple columns:

```
WHERE 12345 IN (HomeZipCode, OfficeZipCode)
```

This is very useful to me, but, being me, I want more.  Can I specify multiple values for that third example?

```
WHERE !?{12345,34567,56789}?! IN (HomeZipCode, OfficeZipCode)
```

So far, I've not found anything that allows a way to specify those multiple values without repeating the `VALUE IN (COL_LIST)` syntax.

```
WHERE 
(12345 IN (HomeZipCode, OfficeZipCode)) OR 
(34567 IN (HomeZipCode, OfficeZipCode)) OR 
(56789 IN (HomeZipCode, OfficeZipCode))
```

or

```
WHERE
(HomeZipCode IN (12345, 34567, 56789)) OR
(OfficeZipCode IN (12345, 34567, 56789))
```

Ideally I'd like to have the column or value list specified only once so the list is maintained in one location in code.

Comment: (+1) I didn't know about the possibility to reverse `IN` operator - it's really cool feature! thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use table value constructor to specify multiple values and use it with `IN` operator

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
OUTER APPLY (VALUES (12345), (34567), (56789)) AS [set](zip)
WHERE [set].zip IN (HomeZipCode, OfficeZipCode)
```

---

variant with multiple `UNION` instead of `VALUES`

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT '12345'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '34567'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '56789') AS [set](zip)
WHERE [set].zip IN (HomeZipCode, OfficeZipCode)
```

Comment: Finally got around to trying this, and this seems like the ideal solution.  Both (as of this writing) solutions are workable, but for ease of understanding in the code, I like this one better.  Can the VALUES clause be populated with the results of a query?

Comment: You do not need to populate `VALUES` clause with the query results. You can simply replace `VALUES` clause by the query. (btw, the table value constrictor is just a syntax sugar for multiple UNION statements)

Answer (score 0):

This is where I would use a split function (you can grab the code for one from many google-able sources) to split the comma-separated list of zip codes into a derived table, and then join to it on

```
  HomeZipCode = value
OR OfficeZipCode = value
```

Or simply on

```
 value IN (HomeZipCode, OfficeZipCode)
```

Comment: I'm not sure that works.  I tried creating a table (say, [AllowedValues]) and it had one column, [ZipCode].

So long as the table had one value, this worked:

     WHERE (SELECT ZipCode FROM AllowedValues) IN (HomeZipCode, WorkZipCode)

but as soon as I added a second value, I got the "sub-select returned more than one value" error code.

Comment: Yes, that's why you need to JOIN the derived table rather than use a sub-select.   Or you could use a WHERE EXISTS(subselect...)